# how to catch a button_click event in event receiver

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

I created a webpart button in visual studio 2013 and deploy it in sharepoint 2013 with a specific function. now I just want to know if it is possible to catch a event of the `Button_click` in event receiver?

I want to conditionate one of my event receiver method by button_click so that if element the button is clicked then don't do anything in ItemAdded for example.

Comment: Is **"specifical"** meant to be "specific" or "special"? Is **"cash"** meant to be "cache" or "catch"? What is **"conditionate"**?

Comment: Is it a on-premise application??

Comment: sorry for my englicsh guy.  **specific** fonction for example fill a tableList with somes items. I mean **Catch**.  I mean **Conditioned**.  it is on cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a property bag value on the site when the button is clicked in your web part.

Use below link to set property bag value.
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/05/12/how-to-write-a-value-into-the-property-bag.aspx

In your item adding event check the value of property bag to verify if the button click was done.

Regards

Hiren Gondhiya

Comment: thx Hiren for the Link you show me it help me to solve it like you see under.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much Hiren, i base myself on what you send me to resolve it like this

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    web.AllProperties["ButtonClick"] = "ButtonHasBeenCliked";
                    web.IndexedPropertyKeys.Add("ButtonClick");
                    web.Update();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

In Event Receiver i just check it like this

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(Url))
  {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
               if(web.AllProperties["ButtonClick"].Equals("ButtonHasBeenCliked"))
               {
                 // Do nothing
               }
     }
  }
```